# Good book on drawing algorithms, preferably in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, drawing, paint

I need a recommendation for a good learning resource on drawing algorithms. I've found plenty of books on algorithms but it is mostly vector and matrix linear algebra, which does not cover the topics I am interest in:

```
efficient drawing of primitives and curves
efficient filling of primitives and paths
multi-sampling or similar techniques for smooth painting
sub-pixel painting
linear, radial, conical and other types of gradients
etc...
```

I am not interested in a book on some API that has those implemented like Cairo, GDI, Qt or similar, but the implementation details themselves. I am not particular interested in big and complex math formulas, I prefer a more visual, intuitive approach with example code, pseudo code also works fine.

Also, before anyone rushing to close the question - I did bother to search for something like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually this kind of book recommendation would belong on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichaelAnderson - No, no it doesn't. This question would get closed and deleted there too. Recommendations of any sort tend to be off topic to all StackExchange sites.

Comment: However, I would recommend any book which includes James D Foley in the author list. His 'Introduction to Computer Graphics' is excellent.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at an 15 year old or older book about computer graphics. For instance "Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice"

Comment: 10x for the suggestions, "Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice" looks like the most informative, although it is dated. According to Amazon a new, THIRD edition is scheduled for release this Autumn as well, hope it is in some performing language and not something modern and slow like Python or Ruby...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can usually find what I need in this book

"Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C" by James D. Foley, Andries van Dam, Steven K. Feiner, John F. Hughes

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend two books:

- Tricks of the Windows Game Programming Gurus - more on 2D graphics
- Tricks of the 3D Game Programming Gurus-Advanced 3D Graphics and Rasterization - more on 3D

and of course "Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C"... as mentioned in previous answers